# Last symbol check of validatin of email

Tags: javascript

```
if(email.charAt(email.length) =="@" ){
    alert("4");
    return false;
}
```

Hi guys!
i'm trying to easyly check email adress.Please dont help me with other methods. i just need to know why code from down is working properly and the one from up is not

```
if(email.charAt(0) =="@" ){
    alert("3");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I wonder why any of it works.

Comment: cant you explain your words please?

Comment: I was running them, and none of them actually works. That's why I said it.

Comment: mb they dont work because you dont have full function?:)

Comment: Although the answer is there already, I still wonder what these code are trying to achieve. Because isn't `charAt()` a method to get a specific index of a string? I wonder why you're checking the 2nd to last and the first element of the string :)

Comment: the function that includes this code making the simplest way to check textbox for email format conformity

Comment: So the code I'm seeing is only a part of it right? Or this is the only piece of code that does the whole checking?

Comment: the code you are seeing is a part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index of charAt starts from 0, so the total array indexes will be from 0 to (email.length)-1. Just try (email.length)-1. Please elaborate your question a bit more if it doesn't works.

Comment: Great! Well, using email.indexOf("@") is a better option in your case. If the function returns -1 means not in the string and if it returns some other positive number means in the string.